# How can I install the latest firefox on raspbian stretch?

Tags: web-browsers

I tried to follow [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-firefox-quantum-on-debian-stretch-linux) guide to do it but the pi disables them because it cannot verify the keys. Does someone have a way to do this? I'm on raspberry pi 3.

precicely this is the error i got

```
Err:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not  available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid InRelease: The following  signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
E: The repository 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Could you explain exactly which step fails in that guide fails, and the error/problem you get ([edit] that in your post)? Not sure which bit you're referring to when you say it can't verify the keys.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: What have you done that results in the mentioned error? Still unclear.

Comment: While the duplicate doesn't mention your error, @answerSeeker, there's not much point trying to resolve the GPG problem, as Firefox 57 won't work anyway. Note that you're trying to use the Debian Sid repositories there rather than the Raspbian ones, and mixing them [might not be the best idea](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#Can_I_mix_packages_from_the_Debian_repositories_with_Raspbian.3F), especially Debian Sid packages and Raspbian Stretch packages.

Comment: That's why the pinning was suppose to help, so it doesn't mix the packages but oh well.